# Compare two json arrays and return common elements java

Tags: java, arrays, json, for-loop

I am a newbie to `java`. I have a `JSONArray`  like this

```
String data1 =  "[{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null}]";
String data2 = "[ { \"_index\": \"sales_csv\", \"_source\": { \"Order Date\": \"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\" }, \"sort\": [ 1576653361740 ], \"_score\": null }, { \"_index\": \"sales_csv\", \"_source\": { \"Order Date\": \"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\" }, \"sort\": [ 1576653361740 ], \"_score\": null }, { \"_index\": \"sales_csv\", \"_source\": { \"Order Date\": \"2016-01-17T18:35:00.000Z\" }, \"sort\": [ 1576653361736 ], \"_score\": null } ]" ;

JSONArray jsonElement1 = new JSONArray(data1) ;
JSONArray jsonElement2 = new JSONArray(data2) ;
```

After conversion:

```
jsonElement1 = [
    {"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},
    {"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},
    {"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null}]
jsonElement2 = [ 
    { "_index": "sales_csv", "_source": { "Order Date": "2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z" }, "sort": [ 1576653361740 ], "_score": null },  
    { "_index": "sales_csv", "_source": { "Order Date": "2016-01-17T18:35:00.000Z" }, "sort": [ 1576653361736 ], "_score": null },
    { "_index": "sales_csv", "_source": { "Order Date": "2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z" }, "sort": [ 1576653361740 ], "_score": null }, ]
```

I need to compare both the `JSONArray` and return the common JSONobjects between both the array and append it to the  new `JSONarray` `output`

Required Output:

```
output = [ 
    { "_index": "sales_csv", "_source": { "Order Date": "2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z" }, "sort": [ 1576653361740 ], "_score": null }, 
    { "_index": "sales_csv", "_source": { "Order Date": "2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z" }, "sort": [ 1576653361740 ], "_score": null }
     ]
```

I tried this answer [Comparing 2 JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209543/comparing-2-jsonarray). But it returns either true/ false.

Here's the Code I tried:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class home {
    public static JSONArray sortJsonArray(JSONArray inputUnSort, JSONArray outputSort) throws JsonProcessingException {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputUnSort.length(); i++) {
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            om.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
            Map<String, Object> map = null;
            try {
                map = om.readValue(inputUnSort.getJSONObject(i).toString(), HashMap.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String jsonstr = om.writeValueAsString(map);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
            outputSort.put(json);
        }
        return outputSort;
    }
    public static JSONArray compareJsonArray(JSONArray jsonElement1, JSONArray jsonElement2) throws JsonProcessingException {
//        Sorting
        JSONArray jsonElement1sort = new JSONArray() ;
        JSONArray jsonElement2sort = new JSONArray();
        jsonElement1sort = sortJsonArray( jsonElement1,  jsonElement1sort);
        jsonElement2sort = sortJsonArray( jsonElement2,  jsonElement2sort);
        JSONArray outputJSONelement = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonElement1sort.length(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonElement2sort.length(); j++) {
                if (jsonElement1sort.getJSONObject(i).toString().equals(jsonElement2sort.getJSONObject(j).toString())){
                    outputJSONelement.put(jsonElement1sort.getJSONObject(i));
                }
            }
        }
        return  outputJSONelement;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String data1 =  "[{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null}]";
        String data2 = "[ { \"_index\": \"sales_csv\", \"_source\": { \"Order Date\": \"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\" }, \"sort\": [ 1576653361740 ], \"_score\": null }, { \"_index\": \"sales_csv\", \"_source\": { \"Order Date\": \"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\" }, \"sort\": [ 1576653361740 ], \"_score\": null }, { \"_index\": \"sales_csv\", \"_source\": { \"Order Date\": \"2016-01-17T18:35:00.000Z\" }, \"sort\": [ 1576653361736 ], \"_score\": null } ]" ;
        JSONArray jsonElement1 = new JSONArray(data1) ;
        JSONArray jsonElement2 = new JSONArray(data2) ;
        out.println(jsonElement1);
        out.println(jsonElement2);
        out.println(compareJsonArray(jsonElement1, jsonElement2));
    }
}
```

The above code looks huge.
Any shortest way to achieve this

Comment: How about using `Set` and `intersect` method?

Comment: I haven't used that. Can u show me in code. I want the code to be minimized and optimized. Coming from python, there are lot of libraries out there in python to make it simple. But in java, i can't find anyone.

Comment: anyway you are doing (n^2) comparison, you can get just remove the sorting

Comment: I used sorting for ordering the JSONobjects. Sometimes, the data gets misordered. so for that case, i used sorting

Comment: the order doesn't matter to find the common items.

Comment: I was comparing  the JSONObjects in the form of strings.

Comment: can you use `JSONObject.similar()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing O(N^2) comparison to find the common elements already, you don't need to sort the array before. Just removing the sorting should also work and reduce a good amount of redundant code

Instead of string comparison use `JSONObject.similar()`